# Как расположить блок под курсором который появляется при наведении?

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть карта SVG и при наведении появляется блок div с информацией при событии mousemove

Но отцентрировать по феншую не получается ..присутствуют статические единицы от которых не знаю как избавиться

Моя попытка

Длина сниппета не позволяет и потому вставляю ссылку: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PobbbZN

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("svg-map");
const info = document.querySelector(".info");
const child = svg.querySelectorAll("path");

svg.onmousemove = function(e) {
  e = window.event;

  child.forEach(function(el) {
    info.style.opacity = 1;
    info.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute("title");
  });

  info.style.left = e.clientX - 200 + "px";
  info.style.top = e.clientY + 20 + "px";
};

svg.onmouseout = function() {
  info.style.opacity = "0";
};
```

Не получается добиться вот такого результата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А «по феншую» — это как?) Только по 'x' или и по 'y' ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME добавил скрин желаемого результат - ну в общем - по Y под курсором а по X всегда по центру то есть одинаково влево и вправо от курсора

Comment: Не могу понять, в чём проблема то? Сделал `info.style.left = e.clientX - 310 + "px";` - вроде, как на картинке. Только короткие строчки в одну строку, но например  ХМАО и ЯНАО с переносом.

Comment: @UModeL  сожми там экран - поёмешь о чём я, там шляпа получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позиционировать нужно по pageX/Y ибо при скролле будет ломаться.
info вынес перед svg-outer, тк родитель(svg-outer) позиционирован относительно, соответственно чайлд берет отступы(left, top) относительно родителя а не верхнего левого края документа

https://codepen.io/dratovannyi/pen/KKNNaQj

```
const svg = document.getElementById("svg-map");
const info = document.querySelector(".info");
const child = svg.querySelectorAll("path");

svg.onmousemove = function (e) {
  e = window.event;

  child.forEach(function (el) {
    info.style.opacity = 1;
    info.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute("title");
  });

  info.style.left = e.pageX - 100 + "px";
  info.style.top = e.pageY + 30 + "px";
};

svg.onmouseout = function () {
  info.style.opacity = "0";
};
```

Comment: круто спасибо ...

Answer (score 2):

По феншую:

```js
let info = document.querySelector(".info");
let svg = document.querySelector("#svg-map");

/***/
// Текстовое значение / видимость определяется только один раз, на входе-выходе
// Пусть mousemove меняет только координаты.

let path = svg.querySelectorAll("path");

for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
  path[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", show_info);
  path[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", hide_info);
}

function show_info() {
  info.textContent = this.getAttribute("title");
  info.style.display = "block";
}

function hide_info() {
  info.style.display = "none";
}

/***/
const INFO_WID = info.offsetWidth;
const X_MAX = window.innerWidth - INFO_WID - 20;
const X_MIN = 10;

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  const Y_MAX = window.innerHeight - info.offsetHeight - 5;
  // Определяется тут, т.к. высота info может меняться (многострочный текст)

  let x = Math.max(X_MIN, Math.min(X_MAX, e.pageX - INFO_WID / 2)); // (*1)
  let y = e.pageY + (e.pageY + 20 < Y_MAX ? (20) : (-info.offsetHeight - 20)); // (*2)

  info.style.left = x + "px";
  info.style.top = y + "px";
});
```

```css
path {
  fill: #f80;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-map" width="100%" height="180">
  <path title="111" d="M   0,10   0,180  80,180  80,10"></path>
  <path title="222" d="M 100,10 100,180 180,180 180,10"></path>
  <path title="333" d="M 200,10 200,180 280,180 280,10"></path>
  <path title="444" d="M 300,10 300,180 380,180 380,10"></path>
  <path title="555" d="M 400,10 400,180 480,180 480,10"></path>
  <path title="666" d="M 500,10 500,180 580,180 580,10"></path>
  <path title="777" d="M 600,10 600,180 680,180 680,10"></path>
</svg>

<div class="info"></div>
```

**(*1)** `Math.max(X_MIN, Math.min(X_MAX, e.pageX - INFO_WID / 2));`: X_MIN, X_MAX — Ограничители, чтобы не выпускать подсказку за рамки экрана. `X_MAX = window.innerWidth - INFO_WID - 20` — Блок как-раз начинает выходить за рамки, когда доходит до `ширина_экрана - своя_ширина`.

**(*2)** `e.pageY + (e.pageY + 20 < Y_MAX ? (20) : (-info.offsetHeight - 20));` — немного другое, к `y`-координате курсора нужно добавить `+20px`, если подсказка не выходит за рамки экрана, или вычесть `-20 - высоту_подсказки`, чтобы она оказалась над курсором.

Comment: + оставил , с выбором лучшего ответа поспешил так как ваш вариант интересней ! спасибо